# how to make a custom field readonly or disabled by user role?

Tags: customization, custom-field, users, user-roles

i am trying to make a simple custom field (made without a plugin) readonly or disabled for a specific user role in functions.php, is this possible ?

thanks

Comment: By "custom field", you mean an `<input>` field?

Comment: yes please, thanks

Comment: And are you referring to the current user? If not, can add your code to the question?

Comment: yes the current user with a specific role, can just view the field content, not able to change it, but the admin can

Comment: I posted an answer. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can get the current user object like so: `$user = wp_get_current_user();`.

The `$user` object would have a `roles` property containing the user's roles, so you can do the following to check if the current user has a specific role: `in_array( 'role_slug', $user->roles )`.

And then in your field HTML, you can use the [`disabled()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/disabled/) and [`readonly()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/readonly/) functions to easily add the `disabled` and `readonly` attributes:

```php
<?php
// Get the current user object.
$user = wp_get_current_user();

// Check if the associated user has a specific role.
$has_role = in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles );
?>
<input name="some_name" <?php disabled( true, ! $has_role ); ?> />
<input name="some_name2" <?php readonly( true, ! $has_role ); ?> />
```

And the above would make the field be disabled/readonly if the current user doesn't have the role `administrator` (note the `! $has_role`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when i add the code to functions.php, the site went down, sorry i know this is because i know nothing about php coding, and i think i need to put the code inside a function or something, can you please show me the whole code for this ?

Comment: That's really the whole code, at least for adding the `disabled`/`readonly` attribute. You just need to implement the code in your code. And don't just put it directly at the root of the `functions.php` file. Can you update the question with all your actual code (that's relevant to the question)?